# Binding to service from a second activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, binding

My understanding is that it is possible to bind to the same service from multiple activities at once. However, I have had a recurring problem when trying to bind to a service from a second activity other than the MainActivity.java from where I started the service with startService.

Here, I have tried to bind to the service (BluetoothLeService.java) from my new activity (SensorDataDisplay.java). This service was origionally started in my MainActivity.java activity and then bound within MainActivity.

I've written some code to check if the bind was successful, and it continuously returns false.

Is there anything that needs to be done differently when binding from a second activity?

SensorDataDisplay.java (second activity)

```
package com.august.customtisensortagclient;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SensorDataDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "SensorDataDisplay";
    TextView tester;
    BluetoothLeServiceForLeft mBluetoothLeServiceForLeft;
    boolean mBoundLeft = false;
    BluetoothLeServiceForRight mBluetoothLeServiceForRight;
    boolean mBoundRight;
    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGattLeft;
    BluetoothGatt bluetoothGattRight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensor_data_display);

        Intent intent = getIntent(); //From MainActivity.java
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");//if it's a string you stored.


        // Checker code (to see if successful bind)
        tester = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tester.append(value);

        if (mBoundLeft) {
            tester.append("TRUEEEEE");
        } else if (!mBoundLeft)
            tester.append("FALSEEEEE");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intentLeft = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.class);
        bindService(intentLeft, mServiceConnectionLeft, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(mServiceConnectionLeft);
        mBoundLeft = false;
    }


    private ServiceConnection mServiceConnectionLeft = new ServiceConnection() {
        // Called when the connection with the service is established
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // Because we have bound to an explicit
            // service that is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.LocalBinder) service;
            mBluetoothLeServiceForLeft = binder.getService();
            mBoundLeft = true;
        }

        // Called when the connection with the service disconnects unexpectedly
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
            mBoundLeft = false;
        }
    };
}
```

BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.java (Please excuse the length. I just wanted to include this in case someone wants to verify my use of the LocalBinder method.

```
package com.august.customtisensortagclient;

import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.UUID;

public class BluetoothLeServiceForLeft extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED_LEFT =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED_LEFT";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED_LEFT =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED_LEFT";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED_LEFT =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED_LEFT";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE_LEFT =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE_LEFT";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA_LEFT =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA_LEFT";


    // Various callback methods defined by the BLE API.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
            new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                                    int newState) {
                    String intentAction;
                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                        intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED_LEFT;
                        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                        broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                        intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED_LEFT;
                        mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                        close();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server and closed.");
                        broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                // New services discovered
                public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED_LEFT);
                        Log.w(TAG, "GATT services discovered.");
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                // Result of a characteristic read operation
                public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                                 int status) {
                    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE_LEFT, characteristic);
                    }
                }
            };

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
        // BluetoothManager.
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothLeServiceForLeft getService() {
            return BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }

    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean disconnect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        Log.w(TAG, "Bluetooth device disconnected from GATT");
        return true;

    }

    public BluetoothGatt getBluetoothGatt() {
        return mBluetoothGatt;
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
}
```

Comment: no, there is no difference if you bind the first time or any time later

Comment: @pskink Do I have to somehow unbind within MainActivity before I bind in my new activity?

Comment: no, you dont have to, no such need

Comment: @pskink perhaps you can glance through my code and help me understand why mBindLeft is returning false, suggesting that I am unable to bind from SensorDataDisplay.java

Comment: @pskink 

Does everything look okay with this line:

            BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.LocalBinder binder = (BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.LocalBinder) service;

Comment: Why do you test the `mBoundLeft` in `onCreate()` when you bound the service in `onStart()`? You should check if the service is bound inside `onServiceConnected`/`Disconnected`.

Comment: @BetaRunner apparently, onStart() is not being called

Comment: @pkskink I added a Log to show whether it has been called, and I see nothing

Comment: @AugustGruneisen how do you start this new activity? That could be why your `onStart()` is not called. Even if it's so strange.

Comment: @BetaRunner I am starting this activity from within a DialogFragment from MainActivity.java

Comment: @pkskink I have now tried a different test to check if onStart is being called, and I can confirm it is being called. Apparently I do not know how to work Log very well. But I can confirm onStart is being called by writing to a textView in my activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you test `mBoundLeft` inside the `onCreate()` method and you bind the service in `onStart()` and unbind it in `onStop()` (also you don't save the transient state in case your app is killed) you will never see if `mBoundLeft` is true (check Activity life-cycle). You should test if the service has been bind inside `onServiceConnected()` using for example `log.d`. You should do something like this:

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
    // Because we have bound to an explicit
    // service that is running in our own process, we can
    // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
    BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.LocalBinder binder = 
             (BluetoothLeServiceForLeft.LocalBinder) service;
    mBluetoothLeServiceForLeft = binder.getService();
    mBoundLeft = true;
    Log.d("ServiceConnection", "Service is connected");
}
```

I recommend you to learn to use `Log`class in Android to debug, it's way better (and a standard) in Android dev.

Comment: I can confirm that this fixed my problem with testing to see if the bind was successful.

However now, I would like to call a method from the bound service. Can I not do so in onCreate? Where should I be writing the code that interacts with my service from within this activity?

Comment: To learn how to use bound services I recommend you to check the Android dev guide [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)